# Filter NSArray of objects to have unique property object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have Manager object, and Account object. Manager object has a property Account.

There is a NSArray of Manager objects, which needs to be unique by Account!

example array:

```
    NSArray *managers = @[Manager1(has Account1), Manager2(has Account1), Manager3(has Account1), Manager4(has Acconut2), Manager5(has Account2)];
```

I need an NSArray with only Manager1 and Manager4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to override [isEqual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:) method inside Manager class (and possibly in Account class as well). After that add Managers to array by first checking, if array already contains Manager with such Account. Check possible solution below:

1. override Manager isEqual

```c
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
  if (object == self) {
    return YES;
  } else if (![object isKindOfClass:[Manager class]]) {
    return NO;
  }

  Manager *manager = (Manager *)object;
  return [self.account isEqual:manager.account];
}
```

2. override Account isEqual (**NB!** only if it is needed)

```c
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
  if (object == self) {
    return YES;
  } else if (![object isKindOfClass:[Account class]]) {
    return NO;
  }

  Account *account = (Account *)object;
  return [self.someUniqueId isEqual:account.someUniqueId];
}
```

3. filter array:

```c
  NSMutableArray *filteredManagers = [NSMutableArray array];
  [managers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Manager *manager, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (![filteredManagers containsObject:manager]) {
      [filteredManagers addObject:manager];
    }
  }];
```

Comment: conditions for creating Account and Manager are not given, so KVC could not work

Comment: btw: if you already use `isEqual:`, implement `hash` as-well and use NSSet and subclasses instead of iterating the array.

Answer (score 9):

What you need is distinctUnionOfObjects

```
[managers valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.Account"];
```

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html)

> @distinctUnionOfObjects
>   The @distinctUnionOfObjects operator returns an array containing the distinct objects in the property specified by the key path to the right of the operator.

The following example returns the payee property values for the transactions in transactions with any duplicate values removed:

```
NSArray *payees = [transactions valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.payee"];
```

The resulting payees array contains the following strings: Car Loan, General Cable, Animal Hospital, Green Power, Mortgage.

The @unionOfObjects operator is similar, but does not remove duplicate objects.

Comment: This is the best answer, it should be the accepted one. +1

Comment: This will return array object of Account & not of Managers.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *managers = // The 5 Manager objects in your example
NSMutableArray *filteredManagers = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *accountsManaged = [NSMutableArray array];

for (Manager *manager in managers) {
    if (![accountsManaged containsObject:manager.account]) {
        [filteredManagers addObject:manager];
        [accountsManaged addObject:manager.account];
    }
}

// filteredManagers now contains Manager1 and Manager4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a separate array uniquely (!) containing the Accounts and further assuming your classes are key value compliant, I'd enumerate through that accounts array and find all managers which manage each account. Then pick the first manager and add it to a new array, like so:

```
NSMutableArray *filteredManagers = [NSMutableArray array];

for (Account *account in accounts) {

   NSArray *managersForAccount = [managers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"account == %@", account];

   [filteredManagers addObject:[managersForAccount firstObject]];

}

// do something with filteredManagers
```